# Where do i put this jQuery in a rails application

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have this chunk on jQuery and currently its living in my index.html.erb and it works well. I have alot of snippets like this that i want to move out of the views and into some other file or files to clean them up. Here is my snippet

```
    $("#request_artist").autocomplete({
        source: function(req, add){
            $.getJSON('<%= ajax_path("artistName") %>', req, function(data) {
      var suggestions = data.suggestions;
                add(suggestions);
            });
        },
    });
```

The problem is that is the getJson call above i use a rails helper to give me the path to the location and when i add this code to application.js it fails because it doesnt know what it is. So my question would be is there a place to put this code and clean up my index.html.erb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your index.html.rb:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var artistNameUrl = '<%= ajax_path("artistName") %>';
</script>
```

And in a separate js file:

```
$('#request_artist').autocomplete({
    source: function(req, add) {
        $.getJSON(artistNameUrl, req, function(data) {
            var suggestions = data.suggestions;
            add(suggestions);
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

What i do to solve your snippet:

```
$("#request_artist").autocomplete({
    source: function(req, add){
        $.getJSON('<%= ajax_path("artistName") %>', req, function(data) {
          var suggestions = data.suggestions;
          add(suggestions);
        });
    },
});
```

I would make sure that the item, with id `request_artist` also has a attribute `data-url` set correctly to `ajax_path("artist_name")`. You make sure that this attribute is filled in correctly in the view.

Inside your javascript no more ruby is needed, it can just use the setting of attribute `data-url`.

```
var url = $(this).attr('data-url');
```

I am not quite sure how to integrate that into the autocompleter code. But i am guessing that this would work:

```
$("#request_artist").autocomplete({
    source: function(req, add){
        $.getJSON($(this).attr('data-url'), req, function(data) {
          var suggestions = data.suggestions;
            add(suggestions);
        });
    },
});
```